# PDO alias code error

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a PDO join query to get the users points, but I am getting this error: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'points''
I am guessing I need to do something like points as p1, but I'm new to aliases and not sure exactly how to code this. I can't seem to find a relevant example on stack overflow.

```
<?php
$pointresults = $dbh->prepare("SELECT
wp_users.ID,
points.points
FROM points
LEFT JOIN points on points.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (wp_users.ID = $user_ID)");

$pointresults->bindParam(':wp_users.ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$pointresults->bindParam(':points.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$pointresults->execute();
$pointrow = $pointresults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php echo $pointrow[0]['points'] ?>
```

Comment: Change `FROM points` to `FROM wp_users`?

Comment: That got rid of the error! I'm not seeing the result printed though. Is that because of my echo statement code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you havnt selected the `wp_users` table.

THe query would be

```
SELECT
wp_users.ID,
points.points
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN points on points.ID = wp_users.ID

WHERE (wp_users.ID = $user_ID)
```

Comment: That's the answer--just got it from stealthyninja above, but it wasn't posted as an answer so I guess I approve yours? Also, can you see why the results are not printing? Something wrong with my echo?

Comment: @Cary5000 its cuz you havnt used :wp_users.ID on the query..please seehttp://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php